# How to align textview to left as previous text view which uses drawable left?

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, alignment, android-drawable

I am working on Android UI implementation. 
I have set `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_change_reporting_mode"` for text view.

Below to text view I have defined on another text view without drawable left.

I have used layout_alignLeft in second text view.

But it is started with that first textview image. I want to align to first textview text. Not from the drawable left image.

I thought of segregating that drawable left image as separate Image view. I hope this will solve this issue.

Any other way to solve this.

Help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some margin from left ,for second textview....it will work for sure

Comment: It is image. I have 6 different image for 6 different drawable folder. It will vary for each device.  I can give the image width as margin left. But it is not an exact one for all devices .

Comment: try once by using fix width..

Comment: No is not working....

Comment: use a transparent icon of same size in second textView OR Use an imageView instead of drawable left.. ,this will work surely

Comment: I too thought of same. There are more rows will come. Is not good to set like this for all the rows. Any other parameter available to set the align left by ignoring the drawable left.

Comment: then only way is to use imageView instead of drawable left,or simple marginLeft will not work properly for all the devices.

Comment: Even If i use image view i can not align left for the text. In next row text view i was not able to refer the previous row layout id's. So i a going with transparent images.

Comment: transparent image will work and for imageView use static size,..provide some static size for ImageView and use that same value for marginLEft for second textView